# Adding regex searches to list in Vim

Tags: regex, vim, pattern-matching, text-extraction

I have been trying to apply the technique offered by ib in another answer on stackoverflow, cannot get it to work in m case.

I am trying to extract a list of numbers from text with reference links in this format

```
[1]:www.example.com    
[2]:www.example.2.com
```

After extracting the numbers I wish to get the maximum value from the list so that I can find the next appropriate number to use.

It was suggested in a excellent answer here:

[How to extract regex matches using Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079561/how-to-extract-regex-matches-using-vim)

to another person that the following format might work:

```
:let nextreflink=[] | %s/\d\zs/\=add(nextreflink,submatch(1))[1:0]/g
```

However, when calling `"echo new"`, in my case, the list is empty.

Any ideas would be very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following explicitly matches "[N]" at the beginning of the line so it's a little more strict.  This is similar to the answer above but it does not remove the numbers from the references (I'm not really sure what's going on with that).

```
let refs=[] | %s/^\[\zs\d\+\ze\]/\=add(refs, submatch(0))[-1]/g
```

This leaves the reference list in tact.  Then you can get the next available reference with:

```
let next = max(refs) + 1
```

This does not take into account skipped numbers.  If the references were `[1, 2, 5]` then `next` will be `6`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to capture the number matched by `\d` by enclosing it in `\(...\)`; the `submatch(1)` refers to the first capture. Also, you probably want to match multiple numbers `\d\+` to support more than nine references.

```
:let nextreflink=[] | %s/\(\d\+\)\zs/\=add(nextreflink,submatch(1))[1:0]/g
```